# typeMismatch Error While parsing JSON data in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Type mismatch Error - expected to decode Array but found dictionary.
I am using local json file embedded in the code. Json file contains the information about packages. I need to pick values and show them accordingly into tableview controller. Please identify what am I doing wrong in codable model or in a code. JSON Parsing not properly handled.

File Format:

```
{
  "packages": [
    {
      "name": "Platinum Maksi 6 GB",
      "desc": "Zengin içerikli Platinum Maksi Paketi ile Turkcell Uygulamalarının keyfini sürün!",
      "subscriptionType": "monthly",
      "didUseBefore": true,
      "benefits": [
        "TV+",
        "Fizy",
        "BiP",
        "lifebox",
        "Platinum",
        "Dergilik"
      ],
      "price": 109.90,
      "tariff": {
        "data": "6144",
        "talk": "2000",
        "sms": "100"
      },
      "availableUntil": "1558131150"
    }
]
}
```

Models:
Base Model

```
struct Base : Codable {

    let packages : [Package]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case packages = "packages"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            packages = try values.decodeIfPresent([Package].self, forKey: .packages)
    }
```

2) Package Model:

```
struct Package : Codable {

    let availableUntil : String?
    let benefits : String?
    let desc : String?
    let didUseBefore : Bool?
    let name : String?
    let price : Int?
    let subscriptionType : String?
    let tariff : Tariff?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case availableUntil = "availableUntil"
            case benefits = "benefits"
            case desc = "desc"
            case didUseBefore = "didUseBefore"
            case name = "name"
            case price = "price"
            case subscriptionType = "subscriptionType"
            case tariff = "tariff"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            availableUntil = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .availableUntil)
            benefits = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .benefits)
            desc = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .desc)
            didUseBefore = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .didUseBefore)
            name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
            price = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .price)
            subscriptionType = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .subscriptionType)
            tariff = try Tariff(from: decoder)
    }
```

}

Tariff Model:

```
struct Tariff : Codable {

    let data : String?
    let sms : String?
    let talk : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case data = "data"
            case sms = "sms"
            case talk = "talk"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            data = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .data)
            sms = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sms)
            talk = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .talk)
    }
```

}

My code:

```
var pack = [Package]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "packageList", withExtension: "json")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        pack = try JSONDecoder().decode([Package].self, from: data)
        print(pack)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding the wrong object. You have to decode always the root object of the JSON which is `Base`.

Get the `Package` array with `base.packages`

```
let base = try JSONDecoder().decode(Base.self, from: data)
pack = base.packages
```

Now you will get two other type mismatch errors, change the type of `benefits` to `[String]` and `price` to `Double`.

You can reduce your structs dramatically: Remove all `CodingKeys` and all initializers and declare all struct members as non-optional (remove the question marks).

**Edit:**

To decode `availableUntil` as `Date` declare it as `Date`

```
let availableUntil: Date
```

and add a custom *date decoding strategy* because the value is a string (It would be easier if the value was `Int`)

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom{ decoder -> Date in
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
    guard let interval = TimeInterval(dateStr) else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Date string cannot be converted to TimeInterval") }
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
}
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
let base = try decoder.decode(Base.self, from: data)
pack = base.packages
```

Comment: thank you and whats about 
let availableUntil : String I want to set it as a date. it value is
`availableUntil": "1558131150"`

Comment: Many Thanks I really appreciated :)

Comment: One more thing if possible I am creating table sections of JSON file data `"subscriptionType": "monthly"` .  values are monthly, yearly and weekly. 
My code:
`enum TableSection: Int {
        case subscriptionType = 0, yearly, monthly, weekly, total
    }
   
    var data = [TableSection: [[String: String]]]()
func sortData() {
        data[.yearly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "yearly" })
        data[.monthly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "monthly" })
        data[.weekly] = packag.filter({ $0.subscriptionType == "weekly" }) }
    `

Comment: giving error - Cannot assign value of type '[Package]' to type '[[String : String]]?'

Comment: Please ask a new question (and accept this one if it was helpful).